# Error exception 'InvalidArgumentException' in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a strange problem with Laravel's schedule that I am trying to solve:

```
ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid scheduled callback event. Must be string or callable'.
```

This is the line of Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->call(\App\Classes\Maintenance::deleteAllRecord())->daily();
```

And this is the function :

```
public static function deleteAllRecord()
{
    $data=\App\LastSeen::all();
    foreach ($data as $dt)
    {
        $dt->delete();
    }
    return 'OK';
}
```

I try also return true , but I had the same problem.I'm sure that the problem is the type of return. Where I make the mistake ? 
I hope I was exhaustive. I wait answer ^_^ have a good day.

Answer (score 7):

You can call `\App\Classes\Maintenance::deleteAllRecord()` inside the callback. Like

```
$schedule->call(function(){
  \App\Classes\Maintenance::deleteAllRecord();
})->daily();
```